# SQL: Find date/time of first valid record in a date range

Tags: sql

Schema:
ID       , int (PK)
datSample, datetime
fltValue , float

I have a table of sample data.

Sometimes the sample values are not captured and the record's fltValue=NULL will be marked invalid.

I need to run a report within the following date range {datRptStart,datRptEnd}

I must extract & display the first and last VALID datSample datetime within the {datRptStart, datRptEnd} range .

I do need to display/graph both valid and invalid values in the report

Example Data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is generic SQL, replace `tablename` with your table name. What database are you using? between works with oracle, for other databases you may need to use >= and <=

```
Select ID,datSample, fltValue from tablename where
datSample between datRptStart and datRptEnd
order by datSample
```

Comment: I'm Using MS-SQL 2012

Comment: I do need to also find first valid date, and last valid date within the range

Comment: For first valid record:   SELECT  TOP 1 datSample
FROM tblTankLevel
WHERE  datSample BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-10'  AND    fltSample IS NOT NULL

Comment: You also need to order based on the datSample to use TOP 1

Answer (score 0):

## First ValidDate in Range

```sql
SELECT  TOP 1 datSample
FROM tblTankLevel
WHERE  datSample >= '2018-01-01' AND 
       datSample <= '2018-01-10' AND    
       fltSample IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY datSample ASC
```

## Last ValidDate in range

```sql
SELECT  TOP 1 datSample
FROM tblTankLevel
WHERE  datSample >= '2018-01-01' AND 
       datSample <= '2018-01-10' AND    
       fltSample IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY datSample DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tblTankLevel
WHERE ID >= (SELECT MIN(ID) AS minId
             FROM tblTankLevel
             WHERE datSample > @datRptStart 
             AND datSample < @datRptEnd
             AND fltSample IS NOT NULL)
AND ID <= (SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxId
           FROM tblTankLevel
           WHERE datSample > @datRptStart AND datSample < @datRptEnd
           AND fltSample IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I must extract & display the first and last VALID datSample datetime within the {datRptStart, datRptEnd} range.

This can be done with a union all -- using the all since we don't know the complete data set here. Assuming the datRptStart and datRptEnd are stored in another accessible table you could do the following:

```
select
    'first'           as position
   ,sd.id             as id
   ,min(sd.datsample) as datsample
   ,sd.fltsample      as fltsample
from
    sampledata sd
where
    sd.fltsample between (select datRptStart from tab) and (select datRptEnd from tab)
group by
    sd.id
   ,sd.datsample

union all

select
    'last'             as position
   ,sd_.id             as id
   ,max(sd_.datsample) as datsample
   ,sd_.fltsample      as fltsample
from
    sampledata sd_
where
    sd_.fltsample between (select datRptStart from tab) and (select datRptEnd from tab)
group by
    sd_.id
   ,sd_.fltsample
```